# What is it about this sentence that makes it sound awkward?

Tags: grammar, ambiguity

I have a colleague who wrote:

> We love what this new tool enables us to do that we never could have done before.

And I responded to that it sounds a bit awkward. I've since reworked it into:

> We love that this new tool enables us to build solutions that we never could have built before.

**Update:** Correction from "what" to "that" thanks to comments.

Is it the ambiguity that gets me? Or is there a sentence structure, grammatical rule or definition at play? I'd appreciate a thoughtful explanation that I can't see without the vocabulary to do so.

Comment: "never could" is unusual, "could not" sits much better. Not sure what the official reason is though.

Comment: We love how this new tool lets us do things we never could before.

Comment: Your reworked version isn't grammatical. Did you mean "that" instead of "what"?

Comment: "Never could ... before" actually sounds fine to me. It makes a stronger statement than "could not ... before"; the "could not" version might occur if we once knew how to do those things but forgot or lost the ability.

Comment: A suggested rewrite: "We love what this new tool enables us to do. We never could have done such things before."

Comment: It would be reasonable to *remove* the *have done*. If you found the result awkward, you could finish with e.g. *... that we previously could not* although that sounds a little clumsy to *my* ears.

Comment: "Build solutions" is absolute nonsense. And who in their right mind "loves" a tool? Some sort of screwdriver fetichist? If I were you I wouldn't advertise your improvements of other people's English here. In any case your question is off-topic as proofreading.

Answer (score 1):

The original quote isn’t awkward. It’s an effusive expression of delight at being able to do something new, thanks to the tool.

The restatement, though, *is* awkward. Either replace *what* with *that* as suggested in comments, or add a dash between *build* and *solutions*.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain that using the grammatical terminology I lack? I appreciate it.

Comment: @mbb Which part would you like more explanation about?

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree with one of the answers here; the original quote *is* awkward. There are two clauses in it, just mashed together.

> We love what this new tool enables us to do

and

> [something] that we never could have done before

One possibility would be to say

> We love what this new tool enables us to do – that which we never could have done before.

or

> We love what this new tool enables us to do: what we never could have done before.

However, I see nothing wrong with your reworded version, which is less vague anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"never could" should be "could never". Its an incorrect placement of a negative adverb.

...Which teaches me to never answer questions when I'm tired.

CMOS 16thEd. sec 5.168 - Within a verb phrase, the adverb goes between the auxiliary verb and the principal verb.

"we never could have done before"

'could' is an auxiliary verb (specifically a modal auxiliary verb), 'have done' is the primary verb, and 'never' is the adverb.

'Never' should have been placed between 'could' and 'have done'

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Can you provide a little more detail (e.g. a reference explaining the correct “placement of a negative adverb”)?

Comment: In common usage, I don't think many people follow this rule